# Problem In Opening Appium Inspector with calculator seesion

Tags: appium

"deviceName": "Moto C Plus",
  "udid": "ZZ2222MGJM",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "7.0",
  "appPackage": "com.google.android.calculator",
  "appActivity": "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"

when click on startSession button
error :

Error
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: zipAlignApk failed. Original error: Command 'C:\Users\ANIL\Desktop\android-sdk\platform-tools\zipalign.exe -f 4 C:\Users\ANIL\AppData\Local\Temp\20191017-3868-paf3kz.h4yu\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk C:\Users\ANIL\AppData\Local\Temp\20191017-3868-1e9g3nn.xgdch\appium.tmp' exited with code 3221225781. Stdout: ''; Stderr: ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the `automationName` parameter to your desired capabilities here. Something like:

`automationName: UiAutomator1`

Or

`automationName: UiAutomator2`

You can read about the `automationName` parameter under the Appium docs: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

It basically tells Appium which device-native automation framework to use.

Comment: Thank you so much really appreciated!! It works after adding automationName: UiAutomator1